# How to use variable variable in find view by id

Tags: android

i will like to use variable cb in findViewById as below, but it is giving me an error, any ideas how to do it

```
public class Compare1 extends Activity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.commac1);
    // setdesign();
    ImageView btn=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.comparenow);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int check=1;check<17;check++){
                int a=check;
            String cb="checkBox"+a;
               int id=getResources().getIdentifier(cb, "id", getPackageName());
                CheckBox cb=(CheckBox) findViewById(id);
                if(cb.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(Compare1.this, "you selected" +cb, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }}

        }
    });
```

Comment: why are you not giving the resource id like you did with the imageview?

Comment: @tyczj because there are 16 checkboxes, it will be very messy

Comment: because he have 17. what is the error you are getting?

Comment: i am checking on my device and the application is stopping after i click on imageview. if i remove the for loop and hardcode the cb variable as cb1,cb2... it is working fine

Comment: Please post the logcat output of the error you receiving.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
int id= Compare1.this.getResources().getIdentifier(cb, "id", getPackageName());
```

using `getResources()` alone makes this method exist in the `OnClickListener` object.

Also:

```
(CheckBox) Compare1.this.findViewById(id);
```

Comment: @ hasan if i remove the for loop and hardcode the cb variable as cb1,cb2... it is working fine. no issues with this line.issue is with this line CheckBox cb=(CheckBox) findViewById(id);